# O que significa o parametro depth do método json_encode()?

Tags: php

Algumas vezes reparei que o docs sugere que em vez de eu utilizar o método nativo `\json_encode()` do PHP, ele me sugere usar um método de uma classe para requisições que aparentemente faz a mesma coisa `\GuzzleHttp\json_encode()`, mas dando uma lida nos arquivos dessa classe encontrei o seguinte método:

```
function json_encode($value, $options = 0, $depth = 512)
{
    $json = \json_encode($value, $options, $depth);
    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            'json_encode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
    }

    return $json;
}
```

Eu nunca havia inserido nenhum parametro em json_encode(), a dúvida é o titulo da pergunta:

- O que o parâmetro depth faz ao encodar uma string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele simplesmente limita a profundidade máxima que vai ser processada.

Esse aqui, é um array de profundidade 1:

```
array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
)
```

Esse, é um array de profundidade 2:

```
array(
    array(
        'foo'
    ),
    array(
        'bar'
    ),
    array(
        'baz'
    )
)
```

Se a profundidade do input for maior que `$depth`, o método simplesmente retornará `false`

você pode querer utilizar esse parâmetro para evitar muito processamento. Um array com profundidade maior que 512 (padrão do método), tem grandes chances de ser infinito

Comment: Então informar 512 (que geralmente é o que estou vendo) é totalmente desnecessário ?

Comment: Tem sua utilidade, você pode querer limitar explicitamente o limite de recursão por algum motivo